# View list of Alert Me assignees?

Tags: alert

Can I view a list "Alert Me" users who've been assigned to a specific list/document/event? I'm aware of the "User Alerts" function which allows you to view a user's "Alert Me" subscriptions. I want to do the opposite, by defining a list/document/event and seeing who is subscribed, also it would be nice if you could edit (add or delete users) from that same view.
Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

There is not way to do this in the ootb SharePoint UI.  I think I remember some third party tools that help with alert management.  The other option is to write your own application page that accomplishes this.